# Why am I getting an unexpected end of file error when running a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 || $# -gt 3 ]; then # invalid number of arguments given
    echo "usage: minor3 name [euid]"
else # valid number of arguments given
    echo Good day, $1! Nice to meet you!
    CHOICE=1
    while [ "$CHOICE" -gt 0 && "$CHOICE" -lt 4 ] # print out the menu, obtain user choice, execute appropriate system call using if-else statements, loop if desired
    do
        echo "+*******************************************************************+
              Enter one of the following options:                                 |
              1) List and count all non-hidden files in the current directory.    |
              2) Check if given user (default = current user) is logged in, then  |
              ... list all active processes for that user.                        |
              3) List the sizes and names of the 10 largest files and directories |
              ... in the current directory.                                       |
              4) Exit this shell program.                                         |
              +*******************************************************************+
              > "       
        read CHOICE 
        if [ "$CHOICE" = 1 ]; then
            # list and count all files
            echo test
        fi
        if [ "$CHOICE" = 2 ]; then
            if [ $# = 3 ]; then # euid was given
                # use given user ($2)
                echo given user 
            else
                # use current user
                echo current user
            fi
        fi
        if [ "$CHOICE" = 3 ]; then
            # list sizes and names of 10 largest files/directories
            echo test
        fi
    done
    echo Thanks, $1! Have a great day!
fi
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
cwd0042@cse04:~/3600/min3$ chmod +x minor3.sh
cwd0042@cse04:~/3600/min3$ ./minor3.sh
./minor3.sh: line 51: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Line 51 is the line after the last `fi`, i.e., the line after the last line of my program. I found an earlier stack overflow post that said to use dos2unix, but the Linux server I have to test on is owned by my school, so I don't have the ability to install it, making it not an option. The server uses Linux Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, if that makes a difference.

Comment: If I copy your snippet and paste it into my Vim, he last `fi` is on line 39, not on line 50...

Comment: Probably just a formatting difference. The whole program is there.

Comment: @eckes The wrong line number is from the dos vs. unix line ending issue.

Comment: @jofel: yep. Thought about that when I read your `dos2unix` emulation script.

Comment: Run your code through shellcheck.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `&&` and `||` inside `[ ... ]` which just calls
the [`test` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_%28Unix%29).

Use `-a` and `-o` instead or use two `[...]` expressions:

```
if [ "$#" -lt 2 ] || [ "$#" -gt 3 ] ; then
```

**Another way** is to use the builtin `[[ ... ]]` bash operator.
It allows to use `&&` and `||`:

```
if [[ "$#" -lt 2 || "$#" -gt 3 ]]; then
```

The program also crashes if you do not enter
a number and just type <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Check at least
if `$CHOICE` is empty.

It seems that you have CRLF line ending (dos-like),
use e.g.

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' -- YOURSCRIPTNAME.sh
```

do fix this. This emulates `dos2unix`.

Comment: @ColeDapprich I extended my answer.

Comment: Don't use `-a` and `-o`; they are all but deprecated.

Comment: @chepner It would be nice, if you could sketch the "modern" way and its advantages, such I can optimize the answer.

Comment: @chepner I included the `[[ ... ]]` way into the answer.